# UIAlertController textfield width is way smaller than usual

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, uialertcontroller

So I have a `UIAlertController` with a `UITextField` added for an input but for some reason the textfield appears to be much smaller than it's supposed to be. Any idea why?

**Here is the Screenshot**

[image: Alert view textfield image]

**Here is the Code**

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"This is title"
                                                               message:@"This is message"
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {

    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    textField.placeholder = @"I am a placeholder";

}];


UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Submit"
                                              style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                            handler:nil];

[alert addAction:okAction];


[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Thanks!

Comment: works fine with me on iphone 6 plus.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: It worked for me as well. I shared a screenshot just to show you how it looks but got 2 down votes :) so removed my post. I agree though it was not an answer.

Comment: Try for different simulators and see, if you can reproduce it!!!

Comment: @fzkl do u got any solution, I am also facing same issue.

Comment: No @PavanMore still no solution. Contacted Apple, let's see what happens

Comment: @fzkl ohk Once you get any response let me know Thanks buddy :)

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33434715/1113194

Comment: Same case here, old project, worked OK on iOS8, textfields shrinked on iOS9.

Comment: Same error here, let me know if you guys find something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a very interesting bug. The project we were working on had a library called Pixate Freestyle, which uses CSS to style app's elements. It was breaking the textfields by styling it. We removed it from the project and styled it natively. The problem was solved. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Presenting through the root controller solved my problem:

`[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];`