# UIAlertController not working in iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, uialertview, ios9, xcode7, uialertcontroller

I have added the UIAlertController code showing login and password textfields, it works for iOS 8 but in iOS 9 not works. The textfields shrinks as shown in figure below  [image]

The code I am trying is as follows :

```
 - (void)toggleLoginLdap:(UIViewController *)currentVC
 {

 if ([UIAlertController class])
        {


            self.alertController= [UIAlertController
                                       alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title of Msg"
                                       message:@"Hello"
                                       preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
                                                           NSString *userName = self.alertController.textFields[0].text;
                                                           NSString *password = self.alertController.textFields[1].text;



                                                       }];
            UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                           handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {


                                                               [self.alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                                           }];


            [self.alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
                 textField.placeholder = @"Username/Email";
                 //textField.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = YES;
                textField.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
            }];
            [self.alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
                textField.placeholder = @"Password";
                textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
            }];
            //alertController.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
            [self.alertController addAction:ok];
            [self.alertController addAction:cancel];
            [currentVC presentViewController:self.alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

Also tried to show on rootviewcontroller but no luck , same code works on ios 8. Project is old and having support from iOS 5. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: so the textfields should be in vertical layout or horizontal layout ?

Comment: I just tried your code. It works fine. where are you calling this method toggleLoginLdap ?

Comment: Horizontal layout(One another below) , And it also works for me in new demo project but its not working in my old project (which is created in previous version of xcode).

Comment: toggleLoginLdap called from another viewController .

Comment: please post the mehtod, where you are calling this. Might be you should call this on main thread!!!

Comment: I tried that also using dispacth_async but no luck :(

Comment: probably it is just a glitch.Try if you can reproduce in all simulators!!!

Comment: I tried on ipad air 2 device also and ipad 2 simulator with ios 9 version but the result is same

Comment: Someone else [has the same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721782/uialertcontroller-textfield-width-is-way-smaller-than-usual) but there is no solution given.

Comment: whoever voted this question down needs to give a reason why (even if it was the all knowing guru @rmaddy haha)..I'm having an issue were the text isn't showing up, which was the same bug that iOS 8 created that I fixed months ago...+1 Pavan for posting this

Comment: @whyoz Wasn't me and no one is required to explain their down votes.

Comment: @rmaddy then can you explain why [actionSheet.view setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; isn't working in iOS 9..you probably want me to ask a new question though..

Comment: Same case here, old project, worked OK on iOS8, textfields shrinked on iOS9.

Answer (score 1):

add `[self.alertController.view layoutIfNeeded]` after presenting alertController
I had the same problem and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I've been researching this for more than a day.

I stumbled upon a thread in the Pixate freestyle github.
My problem was that we were using Pixate Freestyle pod

If you take your code and put it in a clean Xcode project, it will look fine. There was a workaround mentioned there; but it's in swift. I'll try to find it and post a link when I do.

EDIT: https://github.com/Pixate/pixate-freestyle-ios/issues/178